# Zend CLI cannot detect DbTable being removed

Tags: php, zend-framework, command-line-interface

I created a DbTable called GameRow by using

```
zf create db-table GameRow games
```

Then a file called GameRow.php is created in models\DbTable directory. I accidentally removed GameRow.php manually. And now when I use the CLI to create another GameRow model, it doesn't allow me to do so

I get the error

```
This project already has a DbTable named GameRow.
```

Look like zf CLI cannot detect that I already removed my GameRow.php

I googled the question and people said that currently ZF CLI cannot remove a component. What should I do? FYI, I use phpStorm as my text editor

Comment: Which version of Zend Framework? (It should state the version number in `README.md`.)

Comment: Zend Framework version 1.12.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create that table manually again. The simplest way is just creating GameRow.php file with this content:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_GameRow extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'games';

}
```

You can also remove all information about GameRow model in .zfproject file and then use zf CLI tool to create it again.